# assert_select in IntegrationTest Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assertion

I come from a Python and Java background with only basic knowledge to CSS, HTML, Ruby and trying to learn web development using Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to follow the tutorial on [Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-strong_parameters). I constantly have a problem reading the correct API or even understanding what the API is doing when I do as it seems there's a lot of ways a certain method could be called and examples are not exhaustively shown there. In particular, I do not understand how to what arguments the `assert_select` method in Listing 7.25 is doing.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                         email: "user@invalid",
                                         password:              "foo",
                                         password_confirmation: "bar" } }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
    assert_select 'div#<CSS id for error explanation>'
    assert_select 'div.<CSS class for field with error>'
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

By referring to [Online APIs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select), if one were to use `assert_select` without code blocks, we will use 2 arguments. However, there is only 1 here in each of the 2 examples, with `#` and `.`, and I'm not too familiar whether this is some Rails/Ruby/CSS syntax, the origins of the syntax seems mixed.

Can someone enlighten me what am I missing out here? I'm not too familiar when to use `#` and when to use `.`, and how we can "cut short" the number of arguments. There seems to always be a lot of play on punctuations like `_` which are not shown here.

Answer (score 1):

`assert_select` can be [called several different ways](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views), including with just a CSS selector, like the code in your question.

[CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) can contain `#` and `.` symbols. Here's what they mean:

- `#` references an HTML element id
- `.` references a CSS class

Ids must be unique within the document. So, `div#error` would find this exact element: `<div id="error">Some error text</div>`.

Classes on the other hand can be reused throughout the HTML document. So, `div.error` would find all elements like this: `<div class="error">Some error text</div>`.

Finally, for what it's worth, `#` and `.` are also used in Ruby to differentiate between class and instance methods. `.` denotes a class method. `#` denotes an instance method. But, that's not what's going on in the `assert_select` method.

Comment: How do we know whether a method can be called using "just a CSS selector"? Everytime I try following the API strictly, one of these things pop out and apparently it works. If a method requires n arguments, I always run into a case where something CSS related is possible, and I don't abide to the n arguments that are required. Is there an exhaustive list I could refer to, to know what is allowed and what is not allowed?

Comment: The docs are here: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails-dom-testing/Rails%2FDom%2FTesting%2FAssertions%2FSelectorAssertions:assert_select.